# Creating a global variable and assigning a random string to it

Tags: robotframework

I want to create a global variable and assign a random letter to that variable.  I want to be able to call this variable globally and paste it into a text box. How can this be done
So far I have tried the following where I attempt to select 6 random characters.

```
** Variables **
@{ORANGES} =  Generate Random String  6  çÑ3ùáâ$æßØ

Test Case
    input text  ${TXTBX_TITLE}  @{ORANGES}
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this in a `Variables` table. From the user guide:

> The main disadvantages [of the variables table] are that values are always strings and they cannot be created dynamically. If either of these is a problem, variable files can be used instead.

As the documentation says, one solution is to use a [variable file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files). A variable file is python code, so you can do any sort of computation that you want.

You can also use [Generate Random String](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Generate%20Random%20String), but you'll need to do it in a keyword that is called during suite setup. For example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library        String
Suite setup    initialize random data

*** Keywords ***
Initialize random data
    ${oranges}=   Generate Random String   6  çÑ3ùáâ$æßØ
    set suite variable    ${oranges}

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    log to console    \nmy random string: ${oranges}
```